# How do I make my event change my variable x?

Tags: java, javafx-8

```
package RockPaperScissors;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application{

    String x; 

    public static void main(String[] args){
        launch(args);
    }

    public void start(Stage primarystage) throws Exception{

        Stage window;
        window = primarystage;
        window.setTitle("Rock, Paper, Scissor");

        Button rockButton = new Button("Rock");
        rockButton.setLayoutX(50);
        rockButton.setLayoutY(50);
        rockButton.setPrefSize(50,20);
        rockButton.setOnAction(e -> System.out.println("Rock"));

        Button paperButton = new Button("Paper");
        paperButton.setLayoutX(120);
        paperButton.setLayoutY(50);
        paperButton.setPrefSize(50,20);
        paperButton.setOnAction(e -> System.out.println("Paper"));

        Button scissorButton = new Button("Scissor");
        scissorButton.setLayoutX(190);
        scissorButton.setLayoutY(50);
        scissorButton.setPrefSize(60, 20);
        scissorButton.setOnAction(e -> System.out.println("Scissor"));

        Label direction = new Label("Pick Rock, Paper, or Scissor:");
        direction.setLayoutX(50);
        direction.setLayoutY(30);

        Pane pane = new Pane();
        pane.getChildren().addAll(rockButton, paperButton, scissorButton, direction);

        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 500, 400);

        window.setScene(scene);
        window.isFullScreen();
        window.show();
    }
}
```

I want to change the variable so that I can compare to a computer generated int. I also would like to know how to update update the label so that the user can see the outcome. Right now I just have the event print out the user's choice in the console. I'm just using that as a place holder. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can for example turn the variable for the user input into a property:

```
StringProperty x = new SimpleStringProperty();
```

The string which the property holds can be updated on a button-event like this:

```
rockButton.setOnAction(e -> x.set("Rock"));
paperButton.setOnAction(e -> x.set("Paper"));
scissorButton.setOnAction(e -> x.set("Scissor"));
```

Then you can listen for the changes made to the property like this:

```
x.addListener(new ChangeListener<String>(){

        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue, String newValue) {
            String outcome = "";
            //determine outcome depending on newValue.intern();
            outcomeLabel.setText(outcome);
        }           

});
```

The statement `newValue.intern();` will give you the updated string. You can update the label you want to display the outcome with using the `setText()` method.